# git push remote1-branch to remote2-branch without checking out a local copy

Tags: git

I really don't want to checkout code on git because I won't be working with it. I just want to be a relay between two remotes. And, keep them in sync. Is there a way to do this in git ?

Like some kind of:

> git push client

I read from the documentation that the last argument has to be a local branch. Can I not checkout a local copy since I won't work on it any way.

In sum I just want to run a:

> git fetch origin

and then a:

> git push client origin/* (equivalent)

to push all code that was committed in origin to (another remote called) client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, because `git push` just needs a commit identifier on your (local) end and a branch name on the remote end.  There's just one thing in the way.

After you `git fetch` from `origin` you have the commits from `origin` locally, found via the names `origin/*`.  Despite names like `origin/master` and `origin/branch`, these are names *in your repository* (they're just keeping track of "where branches were on `origin` the last time we synced up with `origin`).  The one thing in the way of pushing `origin/master` to `client` is, well, that very name, `origin/master`.

The full syntax of a *refspec* (the arguments to `git push` after the remote name like `origin` or `client`) is: `+opt commit-reference : branch-nameopt`.  Most of these parts are optional: the leading `+`, if present, sets the force flag.  The colon `:` and branch-name part are optional *if* the *`commit-reference`* part is a local branch name.  But, the commit-reference can be a raw SHA-1, or a symbolic reference like `HEAD`, or any other name like `origin/master` (or even `stash`, though pushing a stash does not make sense that often).

The branch name you give here, if any, is the one your git gives to the remote.  To simplify a bit, what happens here is that your git calls up the remote git and says: "Here, have some commits, and then please set *your* `master` to SHA-1 ID `1234567...`."  The SHA-1 ID comes from the *left* side of the colon and the branch-name comes from the *right* side of the colon.

When you use a remote-branch name like `origin/master` on the left, you must specify a particular branch name on the right.  The same holds if you use anything other than a local branch name.  When you use a local branch name, though, you can omit the colon *and* the name on the right, and then your git uses your configuration to *figure out* the name to hand to the remote based on the local name.  (Usually it's just "use the local name as is" but if you set `push.default` to `upstream`, it's "use the upstream's local name based on our merge name", which is just a little bit complicated.)

What this means is that after doing a `fetch` (preferably, probably, with pruning and forced updates) you can then do a `push` of everything brought over during the fetch, with code-driven renaming of the `origin/*` remote branches to turn everything into appropriate refspecs.

---

With all that said, there's actually a much better way to deal with this.  Git has the concept of a *mirror repository* that is simply automatically synchronized.  Mirror repositories are a form of "bare" repository that has no work-tree and therefore *cannot* be checked out.  (This means there's no way for the mirror to have any local work done in it, making it suitable for use as a mirror.)  Mirrors are further divided into *fetch* and *push* mirrors.

A *fetch mirror* is simply a perfect copy of some remote.  For instance, suppose you're at a big company and/or behind some firewall, and you want everyone on your side of the firewall to use your copy of some public repository.  You update your mirror once every 30 minutes, or four times a day, or whatever, and then you direct your internal fetches (perhaps 300 or so per hour) against your local repository on your side of the firewall.  This keeps your internal references fast (they're to your internal network and behind your firewall) and means you don't hammer the public repo.

A *push mirror* is somewhat similar but the direction is reversed: you have all your users push to the push mirror, and then you send the push mirror's contents outside your local firewall/network periodically.

Normally any one repository is just one kind of mirror, because fetch and push are not truly symmetric.  In this particular case, though, you have a fetch mirror that pushes to `client` which itself *should be* a fetch mirror (it should fetch from your mirror), but for some reason is set up to be pushed-to from your mirror.

See [the `git remote` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html) and pay particular attention to the (rather skimpily described) `--mirror` option to `git remote add`.